# how many way to access the scope variables in spring-mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Some one please   me to find out the spring  `mvc`  examples,

Because usually, once we `log in`  into the application we will create a session  and put some objects into session . we will access later point of time , request scope as well. but spring MVC3 is difficult to understand even documentation also confusing, but every one giving example is basic examples only.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here, but for starters, Spring 3 is obsolete. Spring 4.2 is nearly RC.

Answer (score 0):

You can access these objects in a JSP/JSTL:

```
applicationScope
cookie
header
headerValues
initParam
pageContext
pageScope
param
paramValues
requestScope
sessionScope
```

As well as any request attributes that you add, including model attributes (who's default name is `command`).

More info here: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30946&seqNum=7

If you want to access HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpSession, add them as arguments to a Spring Controller Handler Method . Spring will pass them in for you.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help ,  those we know how to acccess in JSP using JSTL,   I  need help on how to put the values into the Spring MVC  code based putting in request and response